# IPython Step by step debugging of the imported module

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I would like to set breakpoint in the imported module and debug step by step  from ipython.

I call separate function from ipython, not the whole module, so %run is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my [blog entry](http://blog.roseman.org.uk/2013/09/19/stepping-through-code-in-ipython/) for a full description.

In summary:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
ipdb = Pdb()
ipdb.runcall(my_imported_function, args...)
```