# Debug/ Gain visibility into step by step working of imported module

Tags: python, debugging, python-import, pdb

I am importing a module in python. Lets call it *ModuleX*

My python code is something like this:

```
import ModuleX

ModuleX.function1(arg1, arg2)
ModuleX.function2(arg3, arg4)
```

I want to see step by step how function1 of ModuleX is working with my passed arguments and generating the required output. There is [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824276/ipython-step-by-step-debugging-of-the-imported-module) but its more like a hacky way of doing it with a major drawback that it doesnt support lists or tuples.

Whats the right way of gaining visibility into step by step functioning of imported modules?

Comment: What about `pdb` doesn’t support lists or tuples?